# codeception public methods that are not tests

Tags: php, testing, codeception

codeception treats every public method as a test. However I have a method that I need to be public. However, it is not a test. Can I somehow annotate it to tell codeception that it should not be run as a test?

Comment: Why you need them to be public then?

Comment: Because I call it from another class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the function with an underscore to let Codeception know it's not a test:

```
public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
{

}
```